# How do I recompile the python files

Tags: python, django, linux, server

I made some changes in my source code. But after I restart the server, Iam not able to see those changes. I'm using Django framework. How do I recompile python code in the linux (CentOS) server.

I already tried restarting the server, installing django-extension.

Comment: is this on your local machine or is this in a production system? what web server and what app server are you using? do you use caching? you will need to be much more specific.

Comment: You can find more information on compilation of python code from https://askubuntu.com/questions/324871/how-to-compile-a-python-file

Comment: Compiling is not the issue here. Python does not need compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different port if its on your local machine